# To insert values in sqlite table from textentrydialog

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to insert values into the table as input given by user in the textentrydialog. i am getting error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error in line 184. First input is a integer other 3 are string

```
def OnAddNew(self, event):
    dlg = GetData(parent = self.panel) 
    dlg.ShowModal()
    if dlg.result_name:
        print "Elements: "+dlg.result_elements+"\n"
        print "Name: "+dlg.result_name+"\n"
        print "Formula: "+dlg.result_formula+"\n"
        print "File: "+dlg.result_file+"\n"
    else:
      print "No Input found\n"
    dlg.Destroy()

class GetData(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "New Molecule", size= (650,220))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)

        self.lblelements = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Elements", pos=(20,20))
        self.elements = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", pos=(110,20), size=(500,-1))
        self.lblnam = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Name", pos=(20,60))
        self.name = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", pos=(110,60), size=(500,-1))
        self.lblform = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Formula", pos=(20,100))
        self.formula = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", pos=(110,100), size=(500,-1))
        self.lblfl = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="File", pos=(20,140))
        self.file = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", pos=(110,140), size=(500,-1))
        self.saveButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Save", pos=(110,170))
        self.closeButton =wx.Button(self.panel, label="Cancel", pos=(210,170))
        self.saveButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SaveConnString)
        self.closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnQuit)
        self.Show()

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.result_name = None
        self.Destroy()

    def SaveConnString(self, event):
        self.result_elements = self.elements.GetValue()
        self.result_name = self.name.GetValue()
        self.result_formula = self.formula.GetValue()
        self.result_file = self.file.GetValue()
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('RAMAN.db')
        cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT max(MOL_NUMBER) FROM MOLECULE")
        maxvalue = cursor.fetchone()[0]       
        cursor= self.conn.execute("INSERT INTO MOLECULE VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s)", ("maxvalue + 1", "name", "formula", "file"))
        #split the elements (because user will give input as 6,8,...) and find the max value of id from table link, execute query to insert values in the link table as (id + 1, elements, maxvalue + 1)
        self.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite` uses `?` as a placeholder for parameters, not `%X`.

Also, `"maxvalue + 1"` is just a constant string. You want `maxvalue + 1` without the quotes.

Comment: cursor= self.conn.execute("INSERT INTO MOLECULE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", (maxvalue + 1, "name", "formula", "file")

Comment: this time i am not getting any error, but it doesnt insert insert the values in the table

Comment: You need to commit the changes. Look through https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: you just see my code i am writing the variable names in the sqlite query correct or not? which i am getting from texentrydialog

Comment: oh sorry. that i forgot

Comment: No. it inserts them like this :  (10, u'name', u'formula', u'fil')

Comment: first column is fine but other columns are variables name

Comment: @TsVilasini stop using string literals where you want a variable. Use a variable or an attribute or whatever expression.

Comment: I didnt get this, what changes should i do i  my code here

Comment: If i remove double quotes from there , it will give me error NameError: global name 'name' is not defined

Comment: @TsVilasini right, because you didn't define a name. You probably want `self.name`.

Comment: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: i wrote this : ("INSERT INTO MOLECULE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", (maxvalue + 1, self.name, self.formula, self.fil))

Comment: self.name isn't actually a string, it's a TextCtrl. You need to extract the string value from there. I'm not going to walk you through how to do every single thing. Just put the appropriate thing in there.

Comment: i am sorry i have no idea , how to do that, please can you help me with that

Comment: @TsVilasini you're still learning basics of Python syntax. I don't think you're ready for tkinter and databases. Go back to basic tutorials and write simpler programs to practice.